# SpringBoot integration tests scan issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm using a multiproject gradle with spring boot 2.0.0.RC1.
One of my subproject is the SpringBoot application and contained my integration tests.

The integration test is marked @SpringBootTest with a WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT. The test failed due to a unresolved dependency (a service declared in a another subproject, sibling of `application`) with gradle command line but succeed in Eclipse IDE.

In the IDE the classpath is unified ; in a terminal the dependencies tree is OK.

All the components are scanned automatically ; all the classes in the various subprojects share the same base package name. I don't understand why some services are not picked up during the scan.

If anyone has an idea ?
How can I debug the beans loading inside a `real WebAppContext test` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project is a gradle multiproject. One is the main application, the others are "components" depending also on spring framework starters.

To achieve this, I added spring-boot and io-dependency-management plugins Doing so in the "components" also come with a side-effect I forgot : the plugin disable the jar task and add a bootJar. And in this project I forgot to disable bootJar and re-enable jar.

Last time I had a warning about main-class not set when building subproject but not this time. Don't know why.

Sorry. Everything's fine. Read the Manual ! ;)

Comment: Exactly this part of the manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal - I've stumbled upon exactly the same problem recently. Wasn't easy to trouble shoot